# Not able to insert value into table (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01722

I keep getting Error report -
ORA-01722: invalid number when I'm trying to insert values into my table.

I'm using oracle. The original problem was that the primary key for table store was a foreign key for table employee and vice versa, hence I could not insert any values. So I changed the foreign key in table store to NULL and tried that but still didn't work

```
create table Store(
Store_ID integer primary key,
Warehouse_ID integer not null,
Employee_ID integer,
Owner_name varchar2 (15) not null,
Store_hours varchar (10) not null,
Store_name varchar (20) not null,
Store_Address varchar2 (35) not null,
  CONSTRAINT Warehouse_FK_Store
  FOREIGN KEY (Warehouse_ID)
  REFERENCES Warehouse (Warehouse_ID),
  CONSTRAINT Employee_FK_Store
  FOREIGN KEY (Employee_ID)
  REFERENCES Employee (Employee_ID));

insert into Store
values (101, 1001, NULL , 'Grant Campbell', '7:00am - 10:00pm', 'Papakura', '331-345 Great South Road, Takanini, Auckland, 2110');
```

Comment: incase of foreign key you have to be that value in parent table then you will be able to push child table that value

Comment: Please add definition for warehouse.

Comment: The insert itself [is fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=dcc747980d580565245f3bc6324d434e)  if you increase the length for some columns. But that won't result in an invalid number. Is there a trigger on the table maybe?

Comment: The posted code is insufficient for us to reproduce the problem (and would apparently throw other exceptions that you haven't reported). We cannot answer your question without a reproducible case.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is right but your Store_Address  varchar size is too short and in your query size is greater then i.e u need to change size of `Store_Address varchar (35)` to  `Store_Address  varchar (255)`

```
   create table Store(
    Store_ID integer primary key,
    Warehouse_ID integer not null,
    Employee_ID integer,
    Owner_name varchar2 (15) not null,
    Store_hours varchar (10) not null,
    Store_name varchar (20) not null,
    Store_Address varchar2 (255) not null,
      CONSTRAINT Warehouse_FK_Store
      FOREIGN KEY (Warehouse_ID)
      REFERENCES Warehouse (Warehouse_ID),
      CONSTRAINT Employee_FK_Store
      FOREIGN KEY (Employee_ID)
      REFERENCES Employee (Employee_ID));

    insert into Store
    values (101, 1001, NULL , 'Grant Campbell', '7:00am - 10:00pm', 'Papakura', '331-345 Great South Road, Takanini, Auckland, 2110');
```

Comment: Why 255 and not 300 or 267? And the length for `store_hours` also needs to be increased

Comment: you can take any number  size but within the varchar2 range .
300 or 267 also valid. There is no reason to take 255 range.

Answer (score 0):

You have problems with the length of the fields.  And you should include the columns being inserted.

I don't know what the types are for the referencing keys, but they need to be the same.

This works:

```
create table Stores (
    Store_ID integer primary key,
    Warehouse_ID integer not null,
    Employee_ID integer,
    Owner_name varchar2 (255) not null,
    Store_hours varchar2(255) not null,
    Store_name varchar2(255) not null,
    Store_Address varchar2(255) not null
    --  CONSTRAINT Warehouse_FK_Store  FOREIGN KEY (Warehouse_ID) REFERENCES Warehouse (Warehouse_ID),
    --  CONSTRAINT Employee_FK_Store FOREIGN KEY (Employee_ID) REFERENCES Employee (Employee_ID)    
);

insert into Stores (Store_ID, Warehouse_ID, Employee_ID, Owner_name, Store_Hours, Store_name, Store_Address)
    values (101, 1001, NULL , 'Grant Campbell', '7:00am - 10:00pm', 'Papakura', '331-345 Great South Road, Takanini, Auckland, 2110');
```

See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7599f74162fea63f40fdfd3ea417ac03).

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=78480e90e29ec319f4446355794c494a) is a version with the foreign key constraints.

Comment: Why 255 and not 215 or 325?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . That's a rhetorical question.  You can choose any appropriate length.  I have an irrational bias toward Mersenne numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Given value '331-345 Great South Road, Takanini, Auckland, 2110331-345 Great South Road, Takanini, Auckland, 2110' size is 100.
Where corresponding created column 'Store_Address' size is 35.

It will work if you increase the size of the column 'Store_Address ' .

Comment: Two other people - not to mention commenters - have already given answers that the posted data is too large for the posted table definition. But we know that would that would cause ORA-12899 and not ORA-01722. The question is a poor one. So whilst it's nice that you want to help, this answer is, alas, superfluous.